# How to change the CSS style of a YouTube iframe

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm embedding a YouTube `<iframe>` in my website. I would like to delete the gray gradient shadow under the title of the video but can't seem to find how.

I did a lot of research on this but found that you can't remove the title anymore. I was wondering if you can still remove the gray shadow under the title. I just want the video to look clean with a play button and I'd add a drop shadow behind it. I need this because this is in line with my design of my website.

Playing with inspect element I found that `.ytp-gradient-top`is the class that causes the gradient shadow, I just don't know how to get rid of it.

Any help is appreciated!

[Gradient shadow I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmiZT.png)

Comment: `.ytp-gradient-top{box-shadow: none !important;}` does this work?

Comment: @Bhanu Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't work

Comment: Can you link to your website? It will help me debug.

Comment: @Bhanu http://badvibesforever.be/herexamen/ here you go bud! Appreciate the help. The iframe is above the footer

Comment: Hey @lucas see this : http://jsfiddle.net/3VVAa/1/  Why don't you try it this way?

Comment: Thank you for that jsfiddle, looks like a great example. I tried this but I get a very weird outcome. When I copy the JSFiddle into my project it displays right but as soon as I replace the URL from the video with my URL, it shows the gradient shadow again

Comment: Let me test that for you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bhanusingh/9kyue7v8/3/ Check this, I added the video you are using it seems to work fine.

Comment: Very strange, even in your JSFiddle I'm seeing the gradient shadow. I've tested it both on Safari & Chrome. Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/YILTBzL

Answer (score 5):

You can't change the CSS of an element within the iframe due to the same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

At the `.shadow` class add `text-shadow:none` and remove the remaining tags that are not working. There are no shadows for that iframe after you add this !
Hope this is what you are looking for...

[image: after removing]